# ¿Cuales son las ventajas de usar promises en Javacript respecto a usar otras formas como la que expongo aqui?

Tags: javascript, promesas

```
function chuleriaClass(eL0) {
    this.errorStr = "";
    this.then = function (eL1) {
        console.log("then ");
        eL1(this);
        return this;
    };
    this.error = function (f) {
        if (this.errorStr != "") {
            f(this, this.errorStr);
        }
        return this;
    };
    if (typeof (eL0) == "function") {
        eL0(this);
    } else {
        this.errorStr = "La funcion no es funcion";
    }
};
var a = new chuleriaClass(function () {
    console.log("Constructor");
});
var b = new chuleriaClass("Rock");
a.then(function (e) {
    console.log(1, this);
    e.errorStr = "Hola que tal";
}).then(function (e) {
    console.log(2);
    console.log(e.errorStr);
}).error(function (e, msg) {
    console.log("Call back de error : de p " + e.errorStr);
});
b.then(function (e) {
    console.log("a -1");
}).then(function (e) {
    console.log("a -2");
}).error(function (e) {
    console.log("Call back de error : de a " + e)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Si bien para el uso particular que le estas dando en tu ejemplo puede funcionar, las promesas están pensadas para trabajar con valores de retorno normalmente asíncronos, que básicamente son el pan de cada día en JavaScript (ajax etc...).

Por poner un ejemplo imagina que con tu implementación vas a hacer un calculo asíncrono, tal que:

```
var a = new chuleriaClass(function () {
    console.log("Constructor");
});
a.then(function (e) {
  console.log(1, this);
  setTimeout(function() {//calculo asincrono de errorStr.
    e.errorStr = "Hola que tal";      
  }, 200);
}).then(function (e) {
    console.log(2);
    console.log(e.errorStr);
}).error(function (e, msg) {
    console.log("Call back de error : de p " + e.errorStr);
});
```

Tu implementación actual no imprime el valor de errorStr.

Ahora usando el api nativo de las promesas vemos que si nos enteramos del nuevo valor aunque sea un calculo asíncrono.

```
var a = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve("calculo async terminado");
  }, 200)
}).then(function(res){
  console.log('res', res);
});
```

Esta es una ventaja de usar las promesas de JavaScript.
Algunas otras que tu implementación no controla son:

- No caer en el 'infierno de los callbacks'.
- Manejo de errores.
- Calculo de varias promesas a la par.
- Disparar evento cuando termine la llamada asíncrona.
- Uso estándar bastante extendido.
- Etc...

Comment: Entendi, tu respuesta es buena, pero setTimeout no es buen ejemplo, por que esta fuera del scope de la clase, si se imprime el valor de this devolvera window.

Comment: @reftferreiras, Uriel tiene razón. No se imprimirá el valor correcto por el sencillo motivo de que la función pasada como parámetro a then será invocada antes de que la función pasada como parámetro a setTimeout sea invocada. Es tan sencillo como realizar la prueba. Por cierto, te recomiendo que pruebes tu implementación, sobre todo el valor que toman los this dentro de las implementaciones de then y error. La palabra clave this es un poco malvada en JavaScript y no se comporta como imaginas.

Comment: Roberto , no entendiste lo que dije, Uriel dio una buena respuesta, pero el setTimeOut SIEMPRE se ejecuta en el escope de root en javascript, no en el escope del objeto que lo declara, si se injecta el scope en la funcion con setTimeOut(function(mthis){ return function(){console.log(mthis.e)};}(this),250); te aseguro que si imprimira el valor de e.